# Restore files from software RAID 1

Tags: docker, mdadm

I accidentally erased my files from my MDADM raid when I created a Docker container and mapped my raid but after that all files in the raid disappeared. The discs are not currently being written or read. I want to ask what is the way I can recover my files? Unfortunately I don't have a backup. Also I am open to any suggestions even to attach disks to Windows machine. This is my Docker compose config file which I used --> https://pastebin.com/PqwEkZ4G

OS: Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

Storage type: HDD

FS type: ext4 not encrypted

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of detail here to answer your question. Can you [edit] it to include which version of Ubuntu you’re using, the output of `lsblk`, and the type of storage (SSD, HDD, etc)? This will make it more likely that you receive an actionable answer 

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what this problem has to do with docker but if you accidently deleted your files then you may be able to recover them. It depends on the type of filesystem and weather it was encrypted or not.

Have a look at this thread for information about how to recover deleted files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files